# Building APK on linux is always blocked

Tags: android, linux, makefile, build

I try to build an apk on linux, and it's always blocked on

**[ 96% 2745/2849]  Generating TOC: out/target/common/obj/JAVA_LIBRARIES/bouncycastle_intermediates/classes.dex.toc**

So is there any methods to deal with it or just to avoid this and build the apk?

Comment: did you try to change directory permissions

Comment: what do you mean to change directory permissions?  I build it with root permission.

Comment: I had same problem and i changed the permesstion and then it was  working fine

Comment: I still don't know what you said. Do you mean I shall change the folder like out to 777?

Comment: Yep you should change the mode of that folder

Comment: I try it but it doesn't work. Anyway, thanks a lot.